# How to retrieve all the request method, request path, request header and request body once spring boot application starts?

Tags: java, spring-boot

We are looking to create a file with all the request methods, path, header and body once spring boot application is up. I mean even before any endpoint is hit. Can this be accomplished? The below code doesn't seem to work.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

@Component
public class EndpointScanner {

    private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

    @Autowired
    public EndpointScanner(RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping) {
        this.handlerMapping = handlerMapping;
    }

    public void scanEndpointsWithRequestBody() {
        Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> handlerMethods = handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods();

        for (RequestMappingInfo requestMappingInfo : handlerMethods.keySet()) {
            HandlerMethod handlerMethod = handlerMethods.get(requestMappingInfo);
            Set<String> methods = requestMappingInfo.getMethodsCondition().getMethods();

            // Check if the endpoint accepts a request body
            if (methods.size() > 0 && handlerMethod.getMethod().getParameterCount() > 0) {
                RequestMapping requestMapping = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
                String[] paths = requestMapping.value();
                // You can also access other details like HTTP methods, headers, etc.

                for (String path : paths) {
                    System.out.println("Endpoint: " + path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "_path, header and body_"? There aren't any until your app starts getting requests.

Comment: look to swagger

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all the request method, request path, request header, and request body once a Spring Boot application starts, you can use an implementation of the `Filter` interface provided by the Servlet API. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

1. Create a new class that implements the `Filter` interface. This class will intercept incoming HTTP requests and extract the desired information. For example:

```java
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RequestLoggingFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // Initialization logic, if any
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

            // Retrieve the request method, path, headers, and body here
            String method = httpRequest.getMethod();
            String path = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
            String headers = httpRequest.getHeader("headerName"); // Replace "headerName" with the desired header name
            String body = httpRequest.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

            // Perform logging or any other processing with the retrieved information
            System.out.println("Request Method: " + method);
            System.out.println("Request Path: " + path);
            System.out.println("Request Headers: " + headers);
            System.out.println("Request Body: " + body);
        }

        // Proceed with the request chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Cleanup logic, if any
    }
}
```

2. Register the `RequestLoggingFilter` in your Spring Boot application. There are a few ways to do this:

   a. If you're using Spring Boot's default embedded servlet container (e.g., Tomcat), you can register the filter as a bean in your `@Configuration` class:

   ```java
   import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

   @Configuration
   public class AppConfig {
       @Bean
       public FilterRegistrationBean<RequestLoggingFilter> requestLoggingFilterRegistration() {
           FilterRegistrationBean<RequestLoggingFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
           registration.setFilter(new RequestLoggingFilter());
           registration.addUrlPatterns("/*"); // Apply the filter to all URLs
           return registration;
       }
   }
   ```

   b. If you're using Spring Boot with Spring MVC, you can register the filter by extending the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class:

   ```java
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

   @Configuration
   public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
       @Override
       public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
           registry.addInterceptor(new RequestLoggingFilter());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Start your Spring Boot application, and the `RequestLoggingFilter` will intercept all incoming requests and log the requested information.

Note: Make sure you replace `"headerName"` in the code with the actual name of the header you want to retrieve. Additionally, keep in mind that logging the request body may have security implications, so use it with caution and ensure that sensitive information is not inadvertently logged.

Comment: [help/gpt-policy](/help/gpt-policy)